# Is php site only using mysql SELECT safe from sql injection attack

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have a website that uses a db to store information for site users.  All the mysql db calls are `SELECT`.  I use `$_GET` to pass variables from page to page that are then used in the mysql `SELECT` calls.  I don't use `UPDATE` or `INSERT` in any of my code.

Do I have to worry about sql injection attacks?
Do I have to protect the db from some other type of attack?

I'm willing to read and learn.  I just don't know if it's necessary in this case.

My db queries all take the form of:

```
$leadstory = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['leadstory'])) {
  $leadstory = $_GET['leadstory'];
}

$query_News = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE lead_story = $leadstory";
$News = mysql_query($query_News, $HDAdave) or die(mysql_error());
$row_News = mysql_fetch_assoc($News);
$totalRows_News = mysql_num_rows($News);
```

Are the first three lines replaced with:

```
$statement = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE lead_story = ?;';");
$statement->bind_param("s", $leadstory);
$statement->execute();
$row_News = $statement->fetchAll();
```

What is the replacement for $totalRows_News?

Do I also have to clean the $leadstory?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up my post trying to add an edit to it!

Comment: All fixed :) (I think, please double check me). I copied the text of your last edit, rolled the question back to the previous revision, then edited to add your last edit again at the bottom. BTW, you can click on the link after 'edited' to go to the version history, where you can roll back edits if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Exploits of a Mom (XKCD)]

That would a be "yes", I think.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='hacker' or name='Admin' and '1'='1'
```

With the supplied name being `hacker' or name='Admin' and '1'='1`

Comment: Thanks Kolink - I was aware of this, but didn't know if it applied to SELECT.  I'll rewrite my SELECT statements.

Comment: It's not useless, it's completely relevant and drives the point home. If I may say so, you appear to be somewhat of a troll. You have downvoted ~3.25 times as often as upvoted (5614 to 1736). Perhaps you should try giving some positive feedback from time to time - it'll make you feel better than downvoting perfectly valid answers for dumb reasons.

Comment: There is too much positive feedback. I am only justifying it. You can't run the query from the comic with the OP code. That's what I call useless.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do have to worry about SQL injection attacks.

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to protect your queries.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I've been reading about this today and will implement it.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer, yes. If any part of your sql statement comes from a request or form submission by the client, you need to sanitize/escape it.

Use PDO and prepared statements, or `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: You appear to have mashed your keyboard and entered some rubbish after *"Use PDO and prepared statements"*

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() IS NOT a replacement to prepared statements! roughly you can call such a replacement **mysql_real_escape_string() + quotes around**

Comment: @Phil nothing actually rubbish. The only this function's drawback is PHP users who massively do not understand how to use it.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I do not believe string escaping and quoting is a good answer when parameter binding is available. I can't understand why people keep putting it in answers

Comment: @Phil because this is your only subjective opinion. Native prepared statements being less handy and often slower than escaping/quoting, yet there is nothing essentially wrong in escaping strings + casting numbers.